# Adding a new field to each array element in .lua

Tags: lua, lua-table, tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

Please tell me, if there are any errors here and how to make the code more clean.

There is a space **"company"**. Inside it's a string **"type"** and **"information"** map. Inside this map is a **"job"** object and an array of **"users"** objects. The "users" array consists of 2 objects. Each object has 4 fields.

I need to add a new field:

> status = "UPDATED"

inside each object in the **"users"** array, under a certain condition

```
"company": {
  "type" : "01",
  "information":
    {
      "job":
        {
          "job_name": "N",
          "job_address": 1670392687114,
          "job_salary": 1234567890123,
          "contacts": 0
        },
      "users":
        [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Alex",
            "rate": 4,
            "address": "bla bla bla"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Jenifer",
            "rate": 5,
            "address": "bla bla bla"
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

My logic is next:

```
if tuple.type == "01" or tuple.type == "02" or tuple.type == "03" or tuple.type == "04" then
   for _, attr in pairs(users) do
      attr.status = "UPDATED"
   end
end
```

Is it correct to add a new ***status="UPDATED"*** field to each object in the array **"users"** here?
Does this entry exist?

And yet, tell me please, can I somehow make the condition in **if** more beautiful? For example analog in Java *list.contains()*

---

***Updated:***

The final version after adding new field **"status"** should look like this (see image)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to add a new status="UPDATED" field to each object in
> the array "users" here? Does this entry exist?

If you want the table to have a status field with value "UPDATED" then `attr.status = "UPDATED"`is correct.

This only makes sense if you'll add more non-updated users to that table later though as you're updating the entire list. you could as well just mark the users table object as updated.

> And yet, tell me please, can I somehow make the condition in if more
> beautiful? For example analog in Java list.contains()

No but you could write your own function.

```
function table.contains(tbl, value)
  for _, v in pairs(tbl) do
    if (v == value) then return true end
  end
  return false
end

if table.contains({"01", "02", "03", "04"}, tuple.type) then
  for _, attr in pairs(users) do
    attr.status = "UPDATED"
  end
end
```

Alternatively you could use a lookup table

```
local isUpdateType = {
  ["01"] = true,
  ["02"] = true,
  ["03"] = true,
  ["04"] = true,
}
```

and later

```
if isUpdateType[tuple.type] then end
```

How to solve this depends very much on what you consider "beautiful" here.

Comment: Thanks a lot again!
About your comment
_"If you want the table to have a status field with value "UPDATED" then attr.status = "UPDATED"is correct."_
That's right, I've updated my question and attached an image. See please.
The new **"status"** field should be in each element of the **"users"** array